Input type date with null value
I have a table with an input type="date" the value of which is take from a database. The input is disabled, so it cannot be edited. Everything fine when the date is set in the database. But sometimes the value in the database is null. In this case the input is not disabled and in the console I can see the suggestion that the value has to be in the format Yyyy/mm/DD and cannot be null.
Is there a way I can have the input date disabled and mantain the value null?
Thanks
The only solution I could find is use div instead of input, but in that case I lose the calendar functionality, and I don't want that.

To make it easier your answer your question, and get better answers, it is strongly recommended to add a bit of code containing a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Otherwise people will make assumptions that can be wrong.

You speak of calendar functionality, but I cannot see any in a disabled input field (in Google Chrome at least). Also, I do not understand how the value can affect the disabled attribute.

I used Firefox, the input is not disabled if the value doesn't correspond to the expected date format.

You can use JavaScript to handle the situation where the date value might be null and ensure the input remains disabled.
<input type="date" id="date_field" disabled>

    <script>

        const dateFromDatabase = null; // pass date from database here

        const dateInput = document.getElementById('date_field');

        // Set the value of the date input if the date is not null
        if (dateFromDatabase) {
            dateInput.value = new Date(dateFromDatabase).toISOString().split('T')[0];
        }

        // Ensure the input is disabled
        dateInput.disabled = true;
    </script>


Here the assumption is that the data comes in through normal Javascript. That's certainly a possibility, but wasn't mentioned in the question. It could be a server-side language.
